# Schedule 40 PVC into threaded conduit hub on top of panel?

Tags: subpanel, conduit

I'm surface mounting this NEMA 3R rated [Eaton BR Loadcenter](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.BR816L125RP.specifications.html) outside. I will be feeding it using 1 1/4" Schedule 40 PVC conduit from above.

Can I use a [1 1/4" PVC Male Terminal Adapter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-1-1-4-in-PVC-Male-Terminal-Adapter-E943GR-CTN/100404003) and screw it into [this 1 1/4" conduit hub](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-1-1-4-in-Conduit-Hub-DS125H2CS/202276739)? I can't figure out if the threads are compatible. I also can't figure out if that conduit hub works with with the Eaton BR Loadcenter. I assume since the conduit is coming from above and terminating 4-5 ft above the ground that Schedule 40 is OK and I don't need to use Schedule 80, is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: Many places require schedule 80 below 8 feet, or 6.5 feet. Check with your LAHJ before having to do it over to suit them. Or use EMT.

Comment: Is this a service box (fed from a meter)? How do you plan to ground the meter and/or carry ground to this box? Rigid or EMT conduit does that quite elegantly; PVC leaves you wondering where the heck to attach a ground wire in a meter pan.

Comment: Is this a service panel (fed from a meter) or a subpanel (fed from some other panel on your property)?

Comment: This is a sub-panel, fed with #8 THHN (4 wires). I know I could downsize the ground to #10 but the place I ordered wire by the foot (120 ft) doesn't sell #10 by the foot, and I want to do a continuous run to the main panel.  I will check if my locality requires schedule 80 above the panel. Do the threads on the meter conduit hub work with these PVC male terminal adapters?